# Databinding for Parent class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-databinding

I want to create a layout which can be used in numerous activity so I create a class like this:

```
open class Parent(var v1: String?,var v2:String?)
class Child(v1:String?,v2:String?, var v3:String?):Parent(v1,v2)
```

I create a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="data"
            type="androidx.lifecycle.LiveData&lt;java.util.List&lt;Parent>>" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/contentAreaColor"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_draw_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:items="@{data}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

In activity1. I try to set below line of code.

```
viewModel.data = MutableLikeData<List<Child>>()
...
mBinding.data = viewModel.data <error here>
```

but the compile explores the error message:

```
>  Type mismatch: inferred type is LiveData<List<Child>> but
> LiveData<(Mutable)List<Parent!>!>? was expected
```

How can I create a layout which can be used in numerous activity?

Comment: You want to create a separate layout file and then use it in different activities / fragments and access it using databinding ?

Comment: I want to create a single layout and use it for multi activities with different type of child data.

Comment: Then what is that data binding error that you have put there about ? It is off topic

Answer (score 0):

Basically, change MutableLiveData<List< Child>>() to

MutableLiveData<List< Parent>>()

```
viewModel.data = MutableLiveData<List<Parent>>()
```